# Freehand selection, copying freehand selected area in c#

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

I'm working on an image editing program. I managed to work out how to select a rectangle from an image, but I'd also like a freehand selection tool.

I got as far as collecting all the points of the selection to a list and that would be enough for drawing but I need to be able to determine which parts of the image are outside the selection and what's inside it.

Also I'd need a way to make sure that the selection is not crossing itself, or if that happens, for the crossed part to get merged into the selection.

I'm not looking for someone to do it for me but I don't even know where to start looking for the answer.

Is there a library or a preferred way to do this?

Thanks in advance[image]

My Code:

The mouseMove event:

```
            if (mdown)
            {
                cut_points.Add(e.Location);

                foreach(Point p in cut_points)
                {
                    if (p.X < cut.X || cut.X == -1) { cut.X = p.X; }
                    if (p.Y < cut.Y || cut.Y == -1) { cut.Y = p.Y; }
                    if (p.X > cut.X + cut.Width) { cut.Width = p.X - cut.X; }
                    if (p.Y > cut.Y + cut.Height) { cut.Height = p.Y - cut.Y; }
                }

                this.Invalidate();
            }
```

The draw event:

```
            using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, Color.White)))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));
            }

            //Freehand
            for (int i = 0; i < cut_points.Count; i++)
            {
                if(i < cut_points.Count - 1)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, cut_points[i], cut_points[i + 1]);
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, new Point(cut_points[i].X + 1, cut_points[i].Y), new Point(cut_points[i + 1].X + 1, cut_points[i + 1].Y));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, new Point(cut_points[i].X, cut_points[i].Y + 1), new Point(cut_points[i + 1].X, cut_points[i + 1].Y + 1));
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, cut_points[i], cut_points[0]);
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, new Point(cut_points[i].X + 1, cut_points[i].Y), new Point(cut_points[0].X + 1, cut_points[0].Y));
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, new Point(cut_points[i].X, cut_points[i].Y + 1), new Point(cut_points[0].X, cut_points[0].Y + 1));
                }
            }

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, cut);
```

Comment: Look for [Point in polygon algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) and polygon intersection algorithms.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you for the tip! I'll look into that

Comment: You should look into the __powerful GraphicsPath__ and its various methods! also try to avoid separate DrawLine calls if the lines shall be continuous; instead use DrawLines. And for freehande selection consider using DrawCurve.

Comment: @TaW Thank you! I will look into that as well

Answer (score 0):

With the help of OlivierJacot-Descombes and TaW I found the solution I needed.
I first started with Raycasting but that is only reliable in the case of non-complex polygons. After some more searching I found that Winding number is probably the best solution for me.

I found a website where they explain the concept really well and provide C code for the winding number calculation as well as some awesome other functions related to computer graphics. (url: http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html)

I translated the code from C to C# and it is working pretty well.

Code:

```
Point p = The point you need to test
Point[] V = The vertices of the polygon as an array of Points
//Important to note: This version of the algorithm doesn't handle a closed polygon 
//if the last Point in `V` is not V[0] as well!
int n = V.Length - 1;

//Returns Integer value depending on the position 
//of the tested point and a line going through 2 other points.
//Returns >0 if Point is left of line <0 if Point is right of line and 0 if Point is on line.
public static int isLeft(Point P0, Point P1, Point P2)
{
    return ((P1.X - P0.X) * (P2.Y - P0.Y)
         - (P2.X - P0.X) * (P1.Y - P0.Y));
}

//Returns the Winding Number of the Point p against the Polygon V[n + 1]
//V[] should contain all of the vertices of the polygon, ending with V[0]
//n should be V.Length - 1;
//It returns 0 if the point is outside the polygon, and any other value (Positive or negative)  if it is inside
public static int wn_PnPoly(Point P, Point[] V, int n)
{
    int wn = 0;

    // loop through all edges of the polygon
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {  
        if (V[i].Y <= P.Y)
        {          
            if (V[i + 1].Y > P.Y)
            {     
                if (isLeft(V[i], V[i + 1], P) > 0)
                {  
                    ++wn;
                } 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (V[i + 1].Y <= P.Y)
            {
                if (isLeft(V[i], V[i + 1], P) < 0)
                {
                    --wn;
                }
            }
        }
    }
        return wn;
}
```